# mysql error 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Pessoal ja pesquisei vários outros tópicos sobre este erro e nenhum resolveu o meu problema por isto estou postando aqui para vocês.
É o seguinte: tenho uma tabela chamada "membros" que ja tem conteúdo e estou criando uma nova tabela chamada membro_fotos que não tem nada nela. Nesta tabela tenho as seguintes colunas: id, membro_id, foto. Tanto o membro_id como o id da tabela membros estão com a seguinte configuração: int-11 e ambas as tabelas estam no engine InnoDB. Meu problema é que quando eu tento criar o Foreign key na tabela membro_fotos ele me da o erro 1512. Por que isto acontece? e como resolver?

```
mysql> desc membros;
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nome                | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nascimento          | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| falecimento         | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

mysql> desc membro_images;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra                       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment              |
| membro_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                             |
| name          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                             |
| created_at    | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| updated_at    | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Utiliza o comando "desc nomeDaTabela" e cola aqui o retorno para cada tabela.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema está no campo `membro_id` que aceita e tem por padrão um valor `nulo`, além do campo `id` na tabela **membros** está configurado para não aceitar números negativos, type `int(11) unsigned`.
Como esperar o mysql faça este tipo de restrição?
Os campos devem ter o mesmo tipo/comprimento de dados.

Utilizei o mesmos campos das tabelas que você forneceu e fiz um rápido teste, passando como não nulo o valor para `membro_id`.

```
create table membros (
  id int not null auto_increment comment 'pk_membros_id',
  nome varchar (100) not null,
  nascimento varchar (10),
  falecimento varchar (10),
  constraint pk_membros_id primary key (id)
  );

  insert into membros
    (nome,nascimento,falecimento)
  values
    ('Maria Joaquina Amaral Pereira', '1914-03-23', '1993-10-07');

 create table membros_fotos (
   id int not null auto_increment comment 'pk_membros_ft_id',
   membro_id int not null,
   name varchar (255),
   created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
   update_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp,
   constraint pk_membros_ft_id primary key (id),
   constraint fk_membros_id_ft foreign key (membro_id) references membros(id)
 );

 insert into membros_fotos
   (membro_id,name)
 values (1,'images/membro_id_001.jpg');
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/326246/2)

Comment: amigo tentei fazer aqui mas deu o mesmo erro. Exclui a tabela e copiei o seu create table membros_fotos e executei ele deu o mesmo erro. Tenho que ver mais alguma coisa na tabela MEMBROS? Ambas estam usando a engine INNODB.

Comment: Veja se consegue alterar sua tabela mebros para aceitar números negativos ou a tabela membros_fotos para não aceitar.
Veja que na tabela membros o campo id está assim: `int(11) unsigned`. Talvez seja isto!

Comment: Amigo deu certinho era isto mesmo. Muito Obrigado. Por gentielza se vc quiser transforme o seu comentário em uma resposta para eu poder marca-la como certa. Obrigadão

Comment: Resposta Editada!

Answer (score 1):

João,
Para estabelecer uma constraint entre duas tabelas, os campos DEVEM SER DO MESMO TIPO E TAMANHO. Você precisa verificar se na tabela membro existe o “membro_id”.

Comment: na tabela MEMBRO exite a coluna ID que é do tipo INT com tamanho 11 e na tabela MEMBRO_FOTOS tem a coluna membro_id é do tipo INT com tamanho 11. São idênticas por isto eu não estou entendendo o motivo do erro.

Comment: O nome do campo ID da tabela membro e igual a "membro_id" ?

Comment: @italo, Não há necessidade de os campos terem os mesmos nomes e sim o mesmo tipo/comprimento" de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo erro aqui e resolvi mudando a "colação padrão" da nova tabela. Estava diferente da que já existia. Mudei também o "formato da linha"

Deixei esses definições iguais em ambas as tabelas

```
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```